# How to reference unnamed variable within list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This block of code gives the correct output however the expression to generate the replacements for numbers is inefficient as it repeats the same expression twice. Is there a way to make this more concise by not repeating the phrase?

Code:

```
numphrase = {3: "three", 5: "five"}
result = [''.join([numphrase.get(key) for key in numphrase if not num % key])
          if ''.join([numphrase.get(key) for key in numphrase if not num % key]) else
          num for num in range(101)]
print(*result, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
threefive
1
2
three
4
five
...
```

Comment: Sounds like a usecase for the walrus operator! If you have at least Python 3.8, `:=` should simplify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an easier way to write `x if x else y` in Python, and that's `x or y`.

So you can write your comprehension as

```
result = [''.join([numphrase.get(key) for key in numphrase if not num % key]) or num
          for num in range(101)]
```